# Артефакты на ui iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity3d

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При переключении платформы на iOS на кнопках появляются следующие артефакты

[image: проблема]

Если изменить платформу на другую, артефактов нет[image: проблемы нет]
С чем это можетбыть связано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите настройки текстур в Unity (каждой конкретной, которая у вас побилась), вкладку для iOS, скорее всего у стоит сжатие текстур в формат PVRTC - из-за этого и появляются артефакты. Попробуйте поставить другой формат (не PVRTC, например ASTC). Также проверьте, что в настройках импорта выключена галочка Generate Mip Maps - это может вызывать то, что для текстур генерируются mip map и выбирается вариант меньшего размера, чем нужно.